# How to wait for getDownloadURL to finish before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm failing to append the URL returned by getDownloadURL on the imageLinks state. I want to continue using the imageLinks state containing all the URLs but it seems the code continues running and doesn't wait for it to return the URL. How can I wait for it to return the links and then append it to the state?

```js
const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] = useState([]);

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (images[i] !== null) {
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + images[i].name;
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, images[i]);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case "paused":
            console.log("Upload is paused");
            break;
          case "running":
            console.log("Upload is in progress");
            break;
          default:
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        alert("Images failed to upload. " + error.message);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          setImageLinks((imageLinks) => [...imageLinks, downloadURL]);
        });
      }
    );
  }
}

console.log(imageLinks); //returns empty array
```

Comment: What's the point of logging the array where you are? What's the point of logging it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick scan of the `UploadTask` class that is returned by [`uploadBytesResumable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytesresumable), it implements all requirement methods of a `Promise`. This means that you can treat it as a promise of the uploading completing, rather than implementing its status callback.

This in turn then allows you to use `Promise.all` to wait for all uploads to complete and all download URLs to be gotten.

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (images[i] !== null) {
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + images[i].name;
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, images[i]);
    const urlTask = uploadTask.then(() => storageRef.getDownloadURL())

    promises.push(urlTask);
  }
}

Promise.all(promises).then((downloadUrls) => 
  console.log(downloadUrls);
  setImageLinks(downloadUrls);
});
```

If you're in an environment/context that supports `async`/`await`, you can also use `await` instead of `then`. In that case you can modify the above, but you can even forego `Promise.all` and do:

```
const storage = getStorage(app);
let urls = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (images[i] !== null) {
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + images[i].name;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, images[i]);
    const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    urls.push(url);
  }
}

console.log(downloadUrls);
setImageLinks(downloadUrls);
```